# Redirect with ASP.NET MVC MapRoute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

On my site, I have moved some images from one folder to another.

Now, when I receive a request for old images '/old_folder/images/*' I want to make a permanent redirect to new folder with these images '/new_folder/images/*'

For example:

```
/old_folder/images/image1.png => /new_folder/images/image1.png

/old_folder/images/image2.jpg => /new_folder/images/image2.jpg
```

I have added a simple redirect controller

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string path)
    {
        return RedirectPermanent(path);
    }
}
```

Now I need to setup proper routing, but I don't know how to pass the path part to the path parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute("ImagesFix", "/old_folder/images/{*pathInfo}", new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index", path="/upload/images/????" });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would do in next way

```
routes.MapRoute("ImagesFix", "/old_folder/images/{path}", new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index" });
```

and in controller like that

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string path)
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("/upload/images/" + path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

first download and install RouteMagic package from [this link](https://github.com/haacked/routemagic) , then redirect your old address to the new address Like the below code :

```
var NewPath = routes.MapRoute("new", "new_folder/images/{controller}/{action}");
var OldPath = routes.MapRoute("new", "old_folder/images/{controller}/{action}");
routes.Redirect(OldPath ).To(NewPath );
```

for more information please check out the following link
[Redirecting Routes To Maintain Persistent URLs](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx/)

Comment: you should post this as a comment

Comment: If you read the link "for more information" you will see that Phil specifically says you can't just pass in two routes to Redirect - you have to use a lambda, I'll put details in a separate answer

Answer (score 2):

Answer above using RouteMagic is a good idea, but the example code is wrong (it's included in Phil's post as a *bad* example).

From the RouteMagic Github demo site [global.asax.cs](https://github.com/Haacked/RouteMagic/blob/master/src/RouteMagicDemo.Web/Global.asax.cs):

```
// Redirect From Old Route to New route
var targetRoute = routes.Map("target", "yo/{id}/{action}", new { controller = "Home" });
routes.Redirect(r => r.MapRoute("legacy", "foo/{id}/baz/{action}")).To(targetRoute, new { id = "123", action = "index" });
```

If you specify two routes, you will be setting up an extra mapping that will catch URLs which you don't want.